# MATLAB function to calculate distance between two coordinates (latitude and longitude)

Tags: matlab, coordinates, distance

How can I calculate distance between two world map coordinates (latitude and longitude) using MATLAB R2015a (in meters)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have access to the MATLAB Mapping toolbox then a simple approximation is to use the [**Haversine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula. Here is an excerpt from the link:

> The haversine formula is an equation important in navigation, giving great-circle distances between two points on a sphere from their longitudes and latitudes. It is a special case of a more general formula in spherical trigonometry, the law of haversines, relating the sides and angles of spherical triangles.

[**Here**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#MATLAB_.2F_Octave) is a MATLAB implementation:

```
function rad = radians(degree) 
% degrees to radians
    rad = degree .* pi / 180;
end; 

function [a,c,dlat,dlon]=haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)
% HAVERSINE_FORMULA.AWK - converted from AWK 
    dlat = radians(lat2-lat1);
    dlon = radians(lon2-lon1);
    lat1 = radians(lat1);
    lat2 = radians(lat2);
    a = (sin(dlat./2)).^2 + cos(lat1) .* cos(lat2) .* (sin(dlon./2)).^2;
    c = 2 .* asin(sqrt(a));
    arrayfun(@(x) printf("distance: %.4f km\n",6372.8 * x), c);
end;

[a,c,dlat,dlon] = haversine(36.12,-86.67,33.94,-118.40); % BNA to LAX
```

Comment: Please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @excaza Done. But if the target site Wikipedia goes permanently offline then the world is on the brink of collapsing and SO will be the lest of our troubles.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to Mapping toolbox then may be function described on [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/distance.html) page could help you.

In that case, you can use the function [distance(LAT1,LON1,LAT2,LON2)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/distance.html) to get the length (in degrees) of the great circle arc connecting both points. Then you can convert this to either km or miles using the [deg2km](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/deg2km.html), [deg2nm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/deg2nm.html) or [deg2sm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/deg2sm.html).

A one liner to get the distance in km would be:

```
deg2km(distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2))
```